# How to change my Google+ connection in "Me" contacts

Tags: people-app

When I set up the social connection in Me I picked the Google+ account that I share with my spouse.  How do I change it to my own google+ account.  In messaging, it picking up the photo of the two of us from our shared Google+ account. I want it to pick up the photo from my personal google+ account.

Thanks.

Comment: What Google account did you use to sync to your phone? Is it the shared account?

Answer (score 0):

A Google+ account is tied to a Google account. So what you can do is using your own account on the Android device instead of the shared one.